# XPath, get next attribute in XML element

Tags: xml, xpath

This XPath expression 
//groups/groupInformation/@groupID[contains(., '10300')] 
does the job of grabbing "10300" from groupID (see below). But, how do I then get text from groupName, groupDescription and so on? Want to retrieve "Carnell - Brown" and so on.  I'm not sure if I am using "element" and "attribute" properly, as I describe this problem.

```
<groupInformation groupID="10300" groupName="Carnell - Brown" groupDescription="The comfortable contemporary design of the “Carnell-Walnut” upholstery collection features deeply stitched back cushioning and shaped chaise seating all surrounded with soft faux leather fabric which offers the beauty and character of leather to create the ultimate collection for any home." groupStyle="Contemporary" groupFeatures="Frame constructions have been tested with various equipment to simulate the home and transportation environments to insure durability. Corners are glued, blocked and stapled. All fabrics are pre-approved for wearability and durability against AHFA standards. Cushion cores are constructed of low melt fiber wrapped over high quality foam. Features metal drop-in unitized seat box for strength and durability. All metal construction to the floor for strength and durability. The reclining mechanism features infinite positions for comfort. Heavyweight faux leather upholstery fabric. Jumbo thread stitched detailing. Collection features the option of either power or non-power pieces." />
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of what's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40983669/290085),

```
//groups/groupInformation/@groupID[contains(., '10300')]/parent::*/@groupName
```

I would suggest,

```
//groups/groupInformation[@groupID='10300']/@groupName
```

because

- It's more concise.
- You'll avoid false matches when `@groupID` is 10300999 or 9991030...

Answer (score 0):

This does it:
//groups/groupInformation/@groupID[contains(., '10300')]/parent::*/@groupName

Comment: Too complicated (and wrong - think false positives like "contains 3"). Use `//groupInformation[@groupID = '10300']/@groupName`.